# Opening Ruby on rails credentials encrypted file in editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

How can i open rails "credentials.yml.enc" file in text editor  to store my credentials in this file in rails 5.2?

Answer (score 5):

You need to invoke:

```
bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Use the below to open with the mentioned Editor:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

From the [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials)

> To edit the credentials file, run bin/rails credentials:edit. This
> command will create the credentials file if it does not exist.
> Additionally, this command will create config/master.key if no master
> key is defined.

Please make sure you have master key setup on `config/master.key` OR on the environment variable `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]`

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `rails credentials:edit`

and

if you want to open with another editor to open with: (for example atom)
`EDITOR=atom rails credentials:edit`

Comment: i have  editor visual studio how can i open it visual studio

Comment: Late answer but it should be `EDITOR=code rails credentials:edit`